# Building Comriva in android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mfcc

I am using Comriva library to extract MFCC features to my speech recognition project. And i have imported the comriva core packages to my project. When i tired to build it im getting this error in gradle,

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex UP-TO-DATE
:app:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:createDebugMainDexClassList UP-TO-DATE
:app:dexDebug
trouble processing "javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.class":
Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.
This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
going on.
However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
It is also often of questionable legality.
If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
building an application, then be forewarned that your application
will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
system. You will be to blame for this problem.
If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
1 error; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 5.524 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

I didn't include any xml libraries so far like simple-xml.

This is my gradle.build file,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.androidhive.sleepApp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/jl1.0.jar')

    compile files('libs/commons-logging-api.jar')
    compile files('libs/cp.jar')
            compile files('libs/http-2.2.1.jar')
            compile files('libs/jama-1.0.2.jar')
            compile files('libs/jl1.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/jogg-0.0.7.jar')
            compile files('libs/lucene-analyzers-3.0.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/lucene-core-3.0.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/lucene-queries-3.0.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/lucene-queryparser-3.0.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/lucene-snowball-3.0.3.jar')
            compile files('libs/jorbis-0.0.15.jar')
            compile files('libs/mdsj.jar')
            compile files('libs/tritonus_remaining.jar')
            compile files('libs/tritonus_share.jar')
            compile files('libs/wstx-lgpl-3.0.1.jar')
            compile files('libs/weka-stable-3.6.13.jar')
            compile files('libs/stax-api-1.0.jar')
            compile files('libs/mp3spi1.9.4.jar')
}
```

Please help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue it was the stax-api-1.0.jar this included the javax.xml.stream.events.* classes after removing the jar i was able to build it successfully. This jar came with the comriva that is why i didn't notice it.

Answer (score 2):

Libraries you haven't explicitly included, can sometimes be brought into your build transitively - as in, a library you did add, depends on another library.

You can run `gradle dependencies` to show a tree of dependencies to analyze which dependency pulls in which transitive dependencies.